# Windows Vista Home Premium - Change owner on files owned by SYSTEM

Tags: permissions, acl, windows-vista

I've copied an entire profile's worth of folders from a Linux Samba share to a newly-formatted Windows Vista Home Premium system.  For some reason, the entire hierarchy became owned by SYSTEM.  Thus, when the user logs in, there are massive problems because the user does not have permission to view or do anything to their own files.

I'm trying to change ownership from SYSTEM to the user, but nothing is allowing me to do that.  Even logged in as Administrator, and I'm not having any luck launching Explorer.exe from PsExec or RunAsSystem.  Is there some utility that will completely reset permissions recursively on a folder and work in Vista Home Premium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Run a command prompt as administrator and then type `takeown /F C:\Path\To\Profile\* /R`

**Option 2**

Right Click on Profile folder and click Properties. Then, go to the Security tab and click Advanced. Go to the Owner tab, and click Edit... Then, select Other users or groups and type your username. Click Check Names, then OK. Select your username, then check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects". Click Apply then OK.

You may also want to try `attrib -S C:\Path\To\Profile\* /S /D` at the command prompt if your files have the system attribute.

Comment: PS. In future, use the backticks (`\``) to escape code. The only downside is you have to use \\` when writing code inside a code block.

Comment: Only been a member for a week thanks for the tip :)